# Export php array data to CSV or Excel

Tags: php, arrays, excel, csv

Variable $list stores an array like the one below. 
I need to pass the array to a CSV or XLS and send headers to download the file.

print_r($list) displays the following:

```
Array
  (
    [0] => Array
       (
         [warehouse] => Array
            (
              [warehouseName] => Warehouse Europe
              [warehouseType] => en detail
            )

          [products] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [productName] => APPAREL SHIRTS
                        [productCode] => 54059761696
                        [measuringUnit] => buc
                        [quantity] => 1
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [productName] => T-SHIRTS - SADAL
                        [productCode] => 54059764755
                        [measuringUnit] => buc
                        [quantity] => 0
                    )


      ........... more data ............


             [5315] => Array
                    (
                        [productName] => Ski - COLBECK 
                        [productCode] => 54080519051
                        [measuringUnit] => buc
                        [quantity] => 3
                    )



              )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [warehouse] => Array
            (
                [warehouseName] => Warehouse US
                [warehouseType] => en detail
            )

        [products] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [productName] => T-SHIRTS - SHEW
                        [productCode] => 40059763901
                        [measuringUnit] => buc
                        [quantity] => 5
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [productName] => SHOESSHOES - OPTIMA
                        [productCode] => 45063556796
                        [measuringUnit] => buc
                        [quantity] => 2
                    )

 ........... more data ............

                [3178] => Array
                    (
                        [productName] => Ski - CASTINE
                        [productCode] => 40080490213
                        [measuringUnit] => buc
                        [quantity] => 1
                    )

            )

      )

)
```

The CSV would look like this in excel: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp1sA.png)
I tried several times but i can't handle it. I think a foreach function and fputcsv should do the trick.

///// LATER EDIT /////

This solved it, thanks!

```
 foreach($list as $item){
     foreach($item['products'] as $product){
         $wName = $item['warehouse']['warehouseName'];
         $wType = $item['warehouse']['warehouseType'];
         $pr =implode(',',$product);
         printf("%s,%s,%s".PHP_EOL,$wName,$wType,$pr);
     }
 }
```

Comment: *I tried several times* so can you share the attempt that was closest to what you want to achieve?!

Comment: Hi, Ali's answer did the trick. I was trying something similar but could only get warehouse names and types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used more variables to be easy to understand . you can reduce them and you can replace **printf** and **echo** function with **sprintf** or **file_put_content** and everything you want

```
foreach($list as $item)
{
    foreach($item['products'] as $product){
         $wName = $item['warehouse']['warehouseName'];
         $wType = $item['warehouse']['warehouseType'];
         $pr =implode(',',$product);
         printf("%s,%s,%s".PHP_EOL,$wName,$wType,$pr);
   }
   echo "...,...,...,...,...,...";
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm without the need for any other improvements. Does exactly what i needed, thanks a lot!